# Android ImageView Not Displaying Image

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

I've searched high and low for an answer but I am completely stumped here.

I have an ImageView that I create in an XML layout.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgProfilePicture"

    android:layout_width="@dimen/image_size"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/image_size"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

    android:scaleType="fitXY"
/>
```

When my app runs, I download a Facebook Profile image via an Async task and store the image on the device's internal memory for later use. When my activity is created, I grab the picture from the internal memory as a Bitmap and set the Image View bitmap with proper scaling (note that I made a custom `Logger` and `FileHandler` for my own uses):

```
Logger.WriteLog(mClassName, subMethodName, "Setting User Profile Image");

FileHandler fileHandler = new FileHandler(getApplicationContext());
Bitmap bitmap = fileHandler.LoadPicture("UserProfileImage");
imgProfilePicture.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, imgProfilePicture.getLayoutParams().width, imgProfilePicture.getLayoutParams().height, false));
```

I am able to verify that the image is present by later:

```
if (imgProfilePicture.getDrawable() == null)
{
    Logger.WriteLog(mClassName, mMethodName,"No drawable present..." );
}
else
{
    Logger.WriteLog(mClassName, mMethodName,"Drawable present..." );
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imgProfilePicture.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

    Logger.WriteLog(mClassName, mMethodName,"Bitmap string = " + bitmap.toString());
}
```

When I run the debugger and set a break point at the last `Logger.WriteLog`, I am able to "View Bitmap" in the debugger console. I don't have enough reputation to post an image but trust me, it is there. I can also see the bitmap's ID in the logcat via the `Logger.WriteLog(mClassName, mMethodName,"Bitmap string = " + bitmap.toString());` line.

**Problem is, when I look at the UI, the image is not present.**

I know that the image is properly placed because if I hard code a dummy drawable in the XML file, it will show up just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you calling :
imgProfilePicture.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, imgProfilePicture.getLayoutParams().width, imgProfilePicture.getLayoutParams().height, false));

?
Have you checked the values of :
imgProfilePicture.getLayoutParams().width
imgProfilePicture.getLayoutParams().height
?

Comment: I am calling it within a `BroadcastReceiver` `onReceive` method that is called when the image has been downloaded and stored in the internal memory. I checked the values via logger and they are both 165.

Comment: Have you checked if you are running on the ui thread when setting the drawable ?

Comment: I believe so, but not sure how to verify that honestly. I can tell you that the image is downloaded and stored to internal memory in an Async task and it broadcasts the message that the task is complete via `LocalBroadcastManager`. The receiver is in the `onCreate` method of my activity.

Comment: Do have a importable android studio project so that i can look into it ?

Comment: I don't sorry. This code is for my company and I can't share it unfortunately.

Comment: @AndreClassen You were close to being right about the threading. I figured it out finally and the problem was that the ImageView is in a Popup Window. In my code to show the popup, I was re-inflating the layout, which in turn, reset all of my set values on the ImageView. I moved some code around and was finally able to get it to work. Thanks a bunch, the answer was not correct, but it absolutely led me in the right direction to identify the problem. Can't thank you enough. That was many days wasted on my part.

Comment: Perfect. No prob, happy coding .